# Quick Controls universal style in PyQt designer

Tags: python, pyqt, stylesheet, qt-designer

I am completely new to PyQt. I want to ask, how I change the stylesheet of my GUI in PyQt Designer. I want to to make a nice looking GUI with Universal Microsoft style. This is the style I want to use: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-universal.html. I am using Python 3.6 and PyQt5 (5.10).

Comment: Are you using qml?

Comment: Am not. A I said, I am completely new to PyQt since yesterday. If you coul please describe how to use it? I did not find any tutorial on how to make Material or Universal app style in python.

Comment: You can not use Material Style or Universal Style in with the QWidgets, which are created by Qt Designer. Qt offers 2 ways to create a GUI, the first is to use the QWidgets and to manage the style one of the forms is Qt Style Sheet, the other way to create a GUI is through QML, and there if you can use those styles. For what you want is difficult to implement in traditional widgets, you need a lot of work. and when you are a beginner I see it difficult, I would say impossible at this time.